# E-mail sending using Gmail

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, gmail

I've developed an email application which can be consist of several attachment.size of those attachments could be 20MB or even higher and i'm using smtp.gmail.com as my host.my issue is it's very slow.i think it may because attachments are uploaded when the Send() mail function is called.is there any option to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottleneck is your Internet connection upload speed.

The only way to resolve this issue is to lease a faster Internet connection.

On most broadband connections, you should expect this upload to take at least 100 seconds (200k per second upload).

Web Email Clients (Like Gmail) get around this with [asynchronous uploaders.](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx) The attachment begins uploading as soon as you select it (even while you are still typing out the rest of your email, before you hit send). Unfortunately, I do not believe there is an API that allows async file upload to GMail for this purpose.

With that said, you may be able to do an async upload to another server, and simply link to that file in the emails that you are sending.

Comment: then why we are not having this issue with the email providers like gmail or yahoo...they first upload the files and when the user press the send button there is just a delay of seconds to sent the email.any idea how they achieve this?

Comment: Yes -- they begin asyncronously uploading the file. Example: You select which file to upload, then it begins uploading while you are still writing the email message.  Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, there's no way to do async attachment uploads to gmail from your code.